# MySQL layered IF statements

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-order-by

I'm trying to accomplish this bit of code:

```
ORDER BY IF(j.groups IS NULL OR j.groups = '',  IF(j.title IS NULL, i.title), j.groups)
```

In English: order by j.groups first if it exists, then by j.title if it eixsts, then finally by i.title. But the above isn't working out.

Comment: NULL should come first or not?

Comment: Shouldn't you have an else-clause for the inner `IF` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY IF(j.groups IS NULL OR j.groups = '', IFNULL(j.title, i.title), j.groups);
```

**OR**

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(j.groups, j.title, i.title);
```

**OR**

```
ORDER BY IF(j.groups IS NULL OR j.groups = '', IF(j.title IS NULL, i.title, 1), j.groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the *else* part of your inner `IF`. Try this:

```
ORDER BY IF(
  j.groups IS NULL OR j.groups = '',
  IF(
    j.title IS NULL,
    i.title,
    j.title -- this was missing
  ),
  j.groups
)
```

But I find this syntax much more readable:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(IF(j.groups = '', NULL, j.groups), j.title, i.title)
```